# C String array's array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am going to store string arrays in an array in C.

For example

```
{
{"hello", "world"},
{"my", "name", "is"},
{"i'm", "beginner", "point", "makes"}
}
```

I'd like to store above data.

I tried to use

```
char *arr1 = {"hello", "world"};
char *arr2 = {"my", "name", "is"};
char *arr3 = {"i'm", "beginner", "point", "makes"}
```

But I don't know how to store those arrays in one array.

Thanks in advance.

ps.

How to print all element with?

```
const char **arr[] = {arr1, arr2, arr3};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a `char**` array, just do :

```
const char *arr1[] = {"hello", "world", NULL};
const char *arr2[] = {"my", "name", "is", NULL};
const char *arr3[] = {"i'm", "beginner", "point", "makes", NULL};

const char **arr[] = {arr1, arr2, arr3, NULL};
```

Note that the `NULL` terminators are here to keep track of the different arrays' sizes, just like in a [NULL-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; arr[i][j] != NULL; ++j) {
        printf("%s ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which would outputs :

```
hello world
my name is
i'm beginner point makes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you help me how to pull from arr[]? arr[0] returns only first element of arr1[].

Comment: How to traverse arr[] with for statement?

Comment: @user2433045 You would need to keep the size of each line of your array somewhere.

Comment: How do you tell how many strings are in each of `arr[0]`,  `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`?  One simple semi-conventional way would be to have a null pointer at the end of each sub-array: `char *arr1[] = { "hello", "world", 0 };`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler indeed the `NULL` terminated array seems to be simpler than keeping array sizes.

Comment: Both methods seems good. For another question if i want to pull only 1 array from arr[] how can I do that? For example if I want to get arr2[] only how can get that?

Comment: @user2433045, doesn't your book on `C` cover that?

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't have that book now... I'll try that book. Thanks!

Comment: @user2433045 I may not have correctly understood your question, but `arr2 == arr[1]`.

Comment: @zakinster After initializing how can I get the array of arr[]? char * temp = arr[0]? It seems that needs some fix for the "char *temp".

Comment: @user2433045 What do you mean by *the array of `arr[]`* ? `arr` is an array of `char**`, `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` are arrays of `char*`, `arr[i][j]` are actual strings (`char*`). Since `arr[0]` is an array of `char*`, you would have to do `char** temp = arr[0]`.

Comment: @zakinster Cause my system's compiler needs constant size for array. "char *arr[]" doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, using C99 compound literals, you can initialize `arr` in one go without the `arr1` sub-variables: `const char **arr[] =
  {
    (const char *[]){ "hello", "world", NULL },
    (const char *[]){ "my", "name", "is", NULL },
    (const char *[]){ "i'm", "beginner", "point", "makes", NULL },
    NULL,
  };` (which looks better when formatted on multiple lines).

Answer (score 8):

Unlike my initial assessment, it can be done with a single literal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* arr[3][4] = {
      {"hello", "world"},
      {"my", "name", "is"},
      {"i'm", "beginner", "point", "makes"}
    };

    printf ("%s", arr[2][3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Arrays 1 and 2 will be padded by zeroes at the end to be of length 4.

output:

> makes

Tested it here: http://ideone.com/yDbUuz

Comment: Note that you're *technically* allocating more `char**` pointers than actually needed, and you don't initialize them. Is this C-standard compliant or compiler tolerated ?

Comment: @zakinster, I don't have my copy of the standard handy, but it's tested on gcc with strict warnings. I'm pretty sure it's standard compliant, one-dimensional arrays are zero padded to fill length constraints, I don't see why it won't translate to higher dimensions.

As for the extra memory, it kind of depends on the data. Your approach will require an extra pointer for every array regardless of the number of pointers in it. Mine will require less NULL pointers for certain arrays length distributions. But this approach is mostly anecdotal, anyway.